# (Hypothesis testing of sum or count) standard error when underlying distribution is skewed and heavy tailed

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, inference

I'm trying to perform hypothesis testing to check if there is a difference in two groups w.r.t. sum of X (continuous RV such as revenue) and sum of Y (integer RV such as count); Each sample in a group will have numerical values for X and Y. I have very large sample for both of groups so CLT kicks in.

The issue is that the distribution of X is unknown but looks very skewed toward lower value and it's slightly heavy tailed (some outliers at the end), definitely not anywhere near normal.

For standard error, I have to know the sample variance of the underlying distribution and I'm not sure how to estimate. I don't think sample variance formula works here given that underlying distribution is not normal but want to double check if I can just use a standard formula for sample variance and devide it by sample size to calculate standard error or is there any other formulas to treat this.

Comment: The term 'standard error' usually refers to the standard deviation of an estimate. What are you trying to estimate with the 'sum of X'? Some context, and discussion of your goal would be helpful.

Comment: Edited the question with details